# t-sql logic to find the receipt amount

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have logic to calculate the sum of receipt amount and receipt date. I am not sure whether the below t-sql works fine for my logic.

I need the max of receipt date  and will go for any receipt date ie., 01-01-2014 this should give me the advance amount paid for the person id.  Also if the max receipt date value is negative then I need to remove that from the calculation.

```
WITH rec_cte (amt,recdate) AS
(
select -40, 01-04-2014 UNION ALL
select -40,01-04-2014 UNION ALL
select 40,20-04-2013  UNION ALL
select -20,10-04-2012 UNION ALL
select 50,20-04-2011 UNION ALL
select 40,20-04-2010 UNION ALL
)

SELECT SUM(amt),recdate from rec_cte
```

Comment: Please reformulate this question. First, the SQL statement has errors and second, it's not clear what results you want/need.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am able to interpret your question, you are looking for SUM(amt) based on ID.

```
 WITH rec_cte AS
(
select 1 as id,-40 as amt, '01-04-2014' as recdate UNION ALL
select 1, -40,'01-04-2014' UNION ALL
select 2, 40,'20-04-2013'  UNION ALL
select 3, -20,'10-04-2012' UNION ALL
select 2, 50,'20-04-2011' UNION ALL
select 1, 40,'20-04-2010'
)

SELECT id, SUM(amt) from rec_cte 
--where recdate= '01-04-2014'
group by id
having SUM(amt)>=0
```

Comment: The issue here is to calculate the receipt amount for the date which can also fall in between two receipt IDs. ie., 20-07-2-13 to 01-04-2014 I need to find the approximate amount only for these receipt date with the corresponding amount.